# UI is degraded after converting to single file

Tags: python, pyqt, pyinstaller

I have created simple UI with QT Designer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QDial" name="dial">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>80</x>
      <y>110</y>
      <width>141</width>
      <height>161</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="invertedAppearance">
     <bool>false</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="invertedControls">
     <bool>false</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="wrapping">
     <bool>false</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="notchesVisible">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLCDNumber" name="lcdNumber">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>80</x>
      <y>40</y>
      <width>141</width>
      <height>61</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menuMain">
    <property name="title">
     <string>Main</string>
    </property>
    <addaction name="actionOfaman"/>
   </widget>
   <addaction name="menuMain"/>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
  <action name="actionOfaman">
   <property name="text">
    <string>test</string>
   </property>
  </action>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

It contains one dial widget and lcd display. Then I used the following to convert it to python:

```
pyuic5 -x main.ui -o mainui.py
```

Then I converted it to single executable:

```
pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed mainui.py
```

Original UI should look like this:

[image]

But running single executable is degrading UI:

[image]

As you can see dial control is degraded and some line has been added under main menu. Conversion is much identical when using cx_Freeze, but I would like to know if pyinstall is not capable to handle `PyQT5/Python36`.

Comment: Try with: `if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle("fusion")`

Comment: that's odd... it works anyways. tks